# Помогите понять IOC Java

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Помогите понять, пожалуйста, правильно ли я понял

1. Бины - это всё, и класс и интерфейс и абстрактный класс, так?

   Меня смущал этот код

   ```
    @Autowired
        IncomingRequestRepo incomingRequestRepo;
   ```

   Учитывая что incomingRequestRepo - это интерфейс! И я не мог понять, почему я создаю переменную типа интерфейс, это же запрещено
2. В Бине должна быть обработка данных, бинами будет всё, кроме моделей и исключений. То есть мне не нужно делать простые классы бинами если я их не использую нигде, а это просто, например модели
3. Если я хочу в классе который является бином вызвать метод другого бина, я должен его обязательно заинжектить

Я правильно понял суть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. бины это всё таки конкретные реализации, но инжектить вы можете и в переменную интерфейса. Но тут есть такой момент, что спринг должен точно понимать, какой класс инжектить по этому интерфейсу, будет неоднозначность - кинет исключение.
2. бинами будет то, что вы сделаете бином, остальное pojo классы. Тоже задавался этим вопросом когда начинал изучать. Если вкратце такую для себя суть определил: бин - это класс который должен управляться контейнером спринга (создание, управление зависимостями), если этого не надо - оставляем pojo.
3. ну в общем да.

Comment: а почему именно spring  собственно? Возможно человек в java EE разбирается

Answer (score 0):

1. Это экземпляр класса, но может быть типа интерфейса, абстрактного класса и тп. Здесь нет отличий от "обычной" java. IOC-контейнер контейнер, который вы использует должен как-то понять экземпляр какого класса инжектить в переменную. Как минимум подходящий для инъекции класс должен быть указан как бин.
2. Здесь распространяются все те же правила и рекомендации по разработке. Смысл в том, что вы получаете возможность инвертировать контроль: класс в котором есть инъекция зависимости не зависит от класса (если переменная типа интерфейс), экземпляр которого в него инжектят. При использовании new она появляется. Советую почитать литература на эту тему, если еще не читали.
3. Нет не обязательно, объект может передаваться как параметр метода например. Инъекция зависимости это просто способ добавления ссылки на объект в другой объект при его создании, вы могли бы делать это сами, но ioc контейнер делает это за вас

Comment: По 3 пункту, это же всё равно по сути инъекция зависимости

Comment: В широком смысле наверное да, но обычно подразумевают, что объект имеет поле, которое будет хранить ссылку на нужный объект и ссылка будет передана через конструктор или сеттер